# How do I stop iterating based on the number of elements on my list?

Tags: python, list

I have a project wherein I have to get the follow-up elements of elements in `on_time`.

For example:

```
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
s_follow_int = [[2, 3], 4, [5, 6], [6, 8], [7, 8], 9, 8, 10, 10, 11]
on_time = [4, 5]
```

The code I have looks like this:

```py
# element in on_time except 1, get follow_finish_act
follow_finish_act = []

for a, d in zip(j_set, s_follow_int):
    if a in on_time and a != 1:
        if len(on_time) > 1:
            follow_finish_act.append(d)
        else:
            follow_finish_act = d
```

Output I am getting:

```
follow_finish_act =  [[6, 8], [7, 8]]
```

Expected Output:

```
follow_finish_act = [6, 7, 8]
```

I am having trouble when length of on_time is more than 1. I think the problem is flattening the irregular lists (can be nested and integer) without duplicates. Since, I cannot get my expected output.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Code I used for trying to flatten output of follow_finish_act

```
def flatten(lss):
    for item in lss:
        try:
            yield from flatten(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item
```

Comment: I get an output of 11 after fixing up to be a little more Pythonic.  This whole thing is very confusing and would be easier to understand if you'd explain what this data represents and what your objectives are.

Comment: @Frank I wanted to get the expected output as shown above which the for loop prohibits me from doing so. I just thought I needed the for loop since I have to check every element  in on_time and see that it is not equal to 1. If it is, then, I do not have to get its follow_finish_act. If it is not, then follow_finish_act is obtained.

Comment: What is your code trying to accomplish ? Can you share more details. Just a sample input and output isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Suraj I am actually getting the follow-up activities (in s_follor_int) of activities in on_time. So far, with the edited code above, I am getting an output as such. But with the succeeding part of the code, I want it to be in a list without duplicates. I tried flattening the output of the code, but it is not working.

Comment: You could use a set to avoid duplicates. I have posted an answer using the same, do check it out.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian I left a comment! Please do see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid duplicates by using `set` instead of `list`

```py
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
s_follow_int = [[2, 3], 4, [5, 6], [6, 8], [7, 8], 9, 8, 10, 10, 11]
on_time = [4, 5]

follow_finish_act = set()

for a, d in zip(j_set, s_follow_int):
    if a in on_time and a != 1:
        if len(on_time) > 1:
            follow_finish_act.update(d)
        else:
            follow_finish_act.update(d)

print(follow_finish_act)
# prints {6,7,8}
print(list(follow_finish_act))
# prints[8,7,6]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But I tried mixing and matching elements in on_time. For on_time = [2, 3], follow_finish_act = [4, 5, 6]. But I am getting an error since 4 is an integer.

Comment: Then try converting all elements in `s_follow_int` to `list`. So you don't get such an error.

Comment: I tried converting it using .tolist, already but s_follow_int is a list already. Also, the succeeding parts of my code wants s_follow_int as it is.

Comment: Alright, you could use this : `s_follow_int1 = [[item] if type(item)==type(4) else item for item in s_follow_int]` to convert all elements to list. I could suggest using `s_follow_int1` for this part of the code and later use the `s_follow_int`. I am not able to think of better logics as I am not able to understand the full objective, hope this helps. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Hello, the code seems to be working when I try to run it as it is. But when I put it together with the code that I have, I am having an error. Will it be alright to continue this in a chat so I could give you the full details of the project I am doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216325/discussion-between-suraj-subramanian-and-john-andrei-gayeta).

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell what you really want, but looking at the code a lot of it seems superfluous. Try this instead:

```
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
s_follow_int = [[2, 3], 4, [5, 6], 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 10, 11]
on_time = [6, 5]

follow_finish_act = []
for a, d in zip(j_set, s_follow_int):
    if a in on_time:
        follow_finish_act.append(d)

print(follow_finish_act)
```

Output:

```
[7, 9]
```

If you then get output like: `[9]`, you could do this afterwards:

```
if len(follow_finish_act) == 1:
    follow_finish_act = follow_finish_act[0]
```

Comment: The thing that I wanted to do is to check if the elements in on_time is not equal to 1, thus the for loop part. If on_time = [1], then, I do not have to get its follow_finish_act. If it is any number, then follow_finish_act is obtained.

Comment: But, if `on_time = [4, 5]`, then if `a` is ever `1`, then `a in on_time` will never be true. If you want to make sure `on_time` itself never has a `1` in it then you could have `new_on_time = [i for i in on_time if i != 1]`